# listener on listview in android

Tags: android, listview, listener

```
 ListView lv=(ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
         lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener()//error:change to <listeners>
{
             public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int row, long arg3) {

                //here is where i got the classCastException.
                String[] tmp = (String[]) arg0.getItemAtPosition(row);

                //tmp[0] ist the Text of the first TextView displayed by the  clicked ListItem 
                Toast.makeText(ReminderListActivity.this, tmp[0].toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                return true;
             }
         });
```

Comment: On second line I am getting an error i.e. change to setOnClickListener and when I click on that I am getting another suggestion to change type of listener. So please help.

Answer (score 0):

change to `lv.setOnItemClickListener`

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix your imports.
you probably import the wrong class and now eclipse thinks you want something else.

Answer (score 0):

You should use below listener:

> ```
> m_listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
>     {
>         @Override
>         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> p_arg0, View p_arg1, int p_arg2, long p_arg3)
>         {
>             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>         }
>     });
> ```